# How commit all files except one with SVN

Tags: file, svn, command, commit

I want to commit all modified files except one using Subversion.

So here is the scenario:

```
$ svn st
M    file1
M    file2
M    file3
M    file4
```

I can do something like this:

```
svn ci -m "Commit 1" file1 file2 file3
svn ci -m "Commit 2" file4
```

But when a large number of files, I'm trying to simplify my work:

```
svn ci -m "Commit 1" `svn st | awk '{print $2}' | grep -v file4`
svn ci -m "Commit 2" file4
```

This solution is very fragile, because this scenario not works:

```
$ svn st
M    file1
M    file2
D    file3
A +  file4
```

I think that SVN does not have a built-in solution for my problem, but I'm not sure. Any other approach?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Option 1, AWK:

```
svn ci -m "Commit 1" `svn st | awk '{print $NF}' | grep -v file4`
svn ci -m "Commit 2" file4
```

Option 2, --targets:

```
svn ci -m "Commit 1" --targets filesToCommit.txt
svn ci -m "Commit 2" file4
```

Option 3, --changelist:

```
svn changelist my-changelist file1 file2 file3
svn ci -m "Commit 1" --changelist my-changelist
svn ci -m "Commit 2" file4
```

Answer (score 14):

You can do it like this:

```
svn diff file4 > tmp.patch
svn revert file4
svn ci -m "Commit 1"
svn patch tmp.patch
```

At this point all files are commited except `file4`

Comment: `svn patch` was added in 1.7. I used `patch -p0 -i tmp.patch` instead of the final line in this example.

Answer (score 5):

Commiting all except one using changelists:

```
svn changelist my-list -R .
svn changelist --remove file4
svn ci -m "Commit 1" --changelist my-list
svn ci -m "Commit 2" file4
```

Answer (score 4):

Although I'm sure you could work out a solution like you propose using a more complex `awk` command line, since we're talking about just one file, why not

1. Copy the file to a temporary location
2. `svn revert` the modified file to get the original back
3. Commit the whole repository
4. Copy the modified file back

Simple, easy, fast.

Answer (score 4):

You can somewhat improve on your approach by adding your files with a script to a [change list](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.changelists.html) and committing it. You can inspect the list to make sure that it contains the right items before committing.

See `svn changelist --help` and `--changelist` option in `svn ci --help`.

Answer (score 0):

Just commit filtered list of files.

```
svn ci `ls | grep -v file4`
```