# svn - what best way to deal with multiple explicit files in status/commit etc

Tags: svn, commit, status, targets, changelist

I have been experimenting with passing several files to svn commit/status/etc :

svn status -u -v file1, file2, file3 ... file1000

svn appears to run svn status -u -v on each filex in turn, is this by design? 
Making the status command/operation very slow via a remote svnserver.

When using a changelist :

svn changelist SVN file1, file2, file3 ... file1000
svn status -u -v --changelist SVN

svn appears to run svn status -u -v once and return the status very much faster, but obviously there are extra step/s to perform  and they have their limitations, see below

changelists can only include files which are currently managed by svn.

Would it make sense to provide an additional operation to create a new changelist on the fly for status/commit, say --newchangelist (removing all files from the existing changelist and creating a new one). In this way explict multiple files could be processed more quickly. Or am I missing something?

Ironically it is quicker to run the below and parse the outout

svn status -u -v

And parse the results resulting output with TCL to filter unwanted files away, --changelist implementation would appear sub-optimal.

--targets is supported on some svn commands (but not all) which may be an option to enhance performance

Why does svn lock/unlock/log NOT provide --changelist option? When most other commands do? At least un/lock supports --targets

Are there any plans to add more changelist capability to SVN?

I would appreciate your thoughts

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.advanced.changelists.html

Subversion's changelist feature is a handy tool for grouping working copy files, but it does have a few limitations. Changelists are artifacts of a particular working copy, which means that changelist assignments cannot be propagated to the repository or otherwise shared with other users. Changelists can be assigned only to files—Subversion doesn't currently support the use of changelists with directories. Finally, you can have at most one changelist assignment on a given working copy file. Here is where the blog post category and photo service tag analogies break down—if you find yourself needing to assign a file to multiple changelists, you're out of luck.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738994/how-commit-all-files-except-one-with-svn?rq=1 is interesting and provides another approach --targets filename